# Complexity when comparing two lists

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, big-o, complexity-theory

```
    for key in string_list:
       if key in new:
          same.append(key)
```

I'm really bad with complexity and I am trying my to best learn. Is the complexity of this code `O(n^2)` because it is comparing two lists? Or is it `O(n)` as I just used one `for` loop? `string_list` and `new` are just two lists.

Comment: please be particular with the tags tag which coding language u r using

Answer (score 1):

The time complexity is O(n^2) because "in" operator has a time complexity of O(n) for average case and you already have a for loop above it so it becomes O(n^2)

You can refer this :

https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity